# How to add a title tag (tooltip) to an HTML table column using tagx and jstl?

Tags: java, html, jstl, jspx, tagx

I have a tagx to create a table with head `<th>...</th>`, based on the table.tagx by/of Spring Roo.

To get text into the head colums is easy, but when it comes to titles, I'm stuck.

This is my current way to fill the table head:

```
<spring:eval var="colCounter" expression="0" />
<table id="_table_${id}_id" class="sortable" >
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <c:forTokens items="${columnLabels}" delims="," var="columnHeading">
        <th>
          <c:out value="${columnHeading}" />
          <spring:eval var="colCounter" expression="colCounter  + 1" />
        </th>
      </c:forTokens>

    [... some more unimportant code here ...]

    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`columnLabels` is a comma separed string containing the the labels. I generated another string called `columnTitles`, which is built just the same way.

So what I'd like to do now, is to add the titles for each column into the `<th>` tag like

```
<th title="${columnTitle}" >
```

I could probably loop through an array with the `colCounter` as index like this

```
<th title="${columnTitles[colCounter]}" >
```

But this would mean some more effort since I'd need to create the array in a completely different way - plus, I'm not very familiar with tagx/jstl (yet).

I still hope, somebody has a solution. I'd be very glad!

Regards,
Stacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about having two separate comma-separated strings.

Use a `List<Heading>`, where `Heading` is a bean containing a `title` property and a `tooltip` property.

Your JSP code is now straightforward, and doesn't need to parse a comma-seperated String into a list of tokens:

```
<c:forEach items="${headings}" var="heading">
    <th title="<c:out value='${heading.tooltip}'/>">
      <c:out value="${heading.title}" />
    </th>
</c:forEach>
```

Java is an OO language. Use objects.

Comment: But you cannot put a "c:out" into the title tag, can you? It's telling me, attribute "title" must not contain the character "<"...
I haven't made that "headings" bean yet though, but it doesn't even work with my current "columnHeadings".

Comment: Yes, you can. You can't put a JSP tag into another JSP tag. But everything that is not a JSP tag or a scriptlet expression is considered as text by the JSP engine. "It", I guess, is your IDE. But your IDE is dumb. Deploy your app and test it. And if you don't like it, you can also use `<th title="${fn:escapeXml(heading.title)}">`

Comment: Well, that's what I did. I deployed it and loaded the respective site. But I get a CannotRenderException, specifically a JasperException which says, in the respective tagx, "title" would be connected with element type "null" and may not contain the character "<".
I cannot give you the original error message, since it's german.
But anyway, I can simply use: title="${heading.tooltip}", can't I?
Btw, I would not consider Spring Tool Suite as dumb.

Comment: You can, if you're sure about the safety of the value of the tooltip.

Comment: I am sure since I literally write the values myself in the respective view where I use that table.
What I'm not sure about though is how I get a bean into the table. The problem is that at the moment, the values for the headings come from the `column.tagx`. The important line looks like that:                                                   
`<c:set var="columnLabels" value="${columnLabels},${label}" scope="request"/>`                  

And honestly, I have no clue what `scope="request"` actually does and how this whole line works. :-/